# Using a word list with wildcards in SQL Server stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of words that I want to exclude from some query results. The list of words is stored in a database table as a comma separated list. eg. bad, awful, worst. (**Note**: It isn't important that they are comma separated. They could just as easily be rows in a table).

I want to be able to utilise this list of words in a stored proc to ensure that keywords from this list don't appear anywhere in my search results. For example, given the following, how would I amend my query to ensure that all search results where filtered for words that appeared in my keywords exclusion list?

```
create table #keywords (column1 varchar(500))

insert #keywords values('bad, awful, worst')

create table #testData (column1 varchar(100))

insert #testData values('This is bad for you')
insert #testData values('This is good for you')
insert #testData values('This is awful for you')
insert #testData values('This is great for me')

SELECT * FROM #testData WHERE column1 like '%you%'

drop table #keywords

drop table #testData
```

As you can probably guess, I want to ensure each of the keywords in the exclusion list are used within wildcards (%) to ensure that the word doesn't appear anywhere in the search results. I am aware of the dangers of SQL injection also, and would be keen to see a way of doing this that minimises any risk.

Any help is appreciated. This will be run on SQL Server 2005 and above.

EDIT -  My main concern is not the comma separated list, but more the way to use the values it contains along with wildcards to exclude particular items from my query results.

Comment: Why comma seperated and not in different records?

Comment: See my comment given to John Gibb below.

Comment: +1 for caring about sql injection!

Comment: Just a thought, shouldn't you match the whole word? e.g. You may filter out 'badger' with wildcard search 'bad'.

Comment: True, but this is a contrived example. The reality is the excluded keywords will be much more complex words that are highly unlikely to appear as part of another word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't store the keywords as CSVs. You're in a database, use it!

Try something like:

```
create table #keywords (column1 varchar(500))

insert #keywords values('bad')
insert #keywords values('awful')
insert #keywords values('worst')

create table #testData (column1 varchar(100))

insert #testData values('This is bad for you')
insert #testData values('This is good for you')
insert #testData values('This is awful for you')
insert #testData values('This is great for me')

select *
from #testData t 
where column1 like '%you%'
  and not exists (
    select *
    from #keywords k
    where t.column1 like '%' + k.column1 + '%'
)

drop table #keywords

drop table #testData
```

Comment: The reason it is stored as comma separated is because the exclusion list is one of many config items in this database. I don't really want to create a new table for any new config item they require. I can get the comma separated values into a temp table in the stored proc. That isn't what concerns me. It is how to do this without making it susceptible to SQL injection. I won't have control over what is added to that exclusion list in future and I'd rather not have it used in a dynamic SQL statement

Comment: Ok. You can use the same table, add a column config_type and then filter in your query's by that column. Eg Select .... FROM configtable WHERE config_type='keywords'

Answer (score 1):

Since you described that the keyword wordslist is there for a reason, I assume you are looking for a recusive solution. This is my surgestion:

```
DECLARE @keywords table (column1 VARCHAR(500)) 

INSERT @keywords VALUES('bad, awful, worst')

DECLARE @testData table (column1 VARCHAR(100)) 

INSERT @testData VALUES('This is bad for you')
INSERT @testData VALUES('This is good for you') 
INSERT @testData VALUES('This is awful for you') 
INSERT @testData VALUES('This is great for me') 

;WITH cte(column1, b, e, keyword) 
AS ( 
SELECT replace(column1, ' ', '') + ',' column1, 1 b, (charindex(',', column1 + ',')) e, cast('%' + substring(column1, 1, (charindex(',', column1 + ',')) - 1)+'%' as VARCHAR(50)) keyword
FROM @keywords
UNION ALL 
SELECT column1, e + 2,charindex(',', column1, e + 1), cast('%' + substring(column1, e + 1, charindex(',', column1, e + 1) - e - 1)+'%' as VARCHAR(50))
FROM cte ch
WHERE charindex(',', column1, e + 1) > 0
) 
SELECT *
FROM @testdata t
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM cte WHERE t.column1 like keyword)
and column1 like '%you%'
```